# Android PDF viewer that maintains Roman Numerals before page 1?

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-viewer, reading, tablet

I have several text books I am trying to read on my Android tablet, and it's very frustrating that the page numbers do not correspond to the numbers written on the page, since there are about 20 to 30 pages of roman numeral prologue.

Is there a PDF viewer that maintains these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Foxit PDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxit.mobile.pdf.lite&hl=en&rdid=com.foxit.mobile.pdf.lite) does this nicely.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I needed!